# Convert seconds since 1-1-1999 to UTC date/time in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have an list of timestamps in the form of seconds since `January 1, 1999 00:00 UTC` (not epoch). I am looking for a way to convert this to a date/time in a more standard format (like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS UTC`). I'm not sure how to do this since its not that more usual "seconds since epoch" format.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to convert to a "seconds since epoch" since it's just a constant offset of 915177600 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with some simple datetime and timedelta stuff

```
d0 = datetime(1999,1,1,0,0,0)
dt = timedelta(seconds = time[0])
d  = d0 + dt 

>>> d
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 19, 13, 28, 55, 317013)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure about what do you need exactly, but I hope that this can help you:

```
x = datetime.datetime(1999,1,1)
y=x + datetime.timedelta(0,1256083200.0)
print('{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(y))
#print:'2038-10-21 00:00:00'
```

Reference:

[What is the standard way to add N seconds to datetime.time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100210/what-is-the-standard-way-to-add-n-seconds-to-datetime-time-in-python)

[How to convert a Python datetime object to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds)

[How can I create basic timestamps or dates? (Python 3.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455616/how-can-i-create-basic-timestamps-or-dates-python-3-4)